# creating a date with variables passed into a method

Tags: ruby, date, methods

I need to create a date as part of a method by passing in 2 parameters.User chooses numeric year and month and these are passed into the method.There is more to it than this but i keep getting the error "comparison of String with 0 failed (ArgumentError)"

```
def printMonth(year, month)
 y= year.to_i
 x= month.to_i
 z= x + 1
 now= Date.new("#{y}, #{x}, 1")
 puts(now)

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to pass three arguments to `Date` constructor, but wrapped it in quotes and passed as one. There's also no reason to convert them to integers to convert them to strings again:

```
now = Date.new(year, month, 1)
```

Comment: @BrianMccomas no problem! Please, accept an answer :) Thanks!